# Editor or Js extension for Textile Tables

Tags: vim, sublimetext2, redmine, textile

Is there anything similar to:

https://github.com/vkocubinsky/SublimeTableEditor

I have to write quite many tables in textile (Redmine) and I'd like to have them in pretty format

```
|_. Header1 |
| row1      |
| row2      |
```

rather than in that ugly one:

```
|_. Header1|
|row1|
|row2|
```

Especially when I want to create more sophisticated tables:

```
|_. Header1 |_. Header2 |
|/2. two lines row1| one|
|two|
|/2. two lines row2| one|
|two|
```

and it should look like this:

```
|_. Header1         |_. Header2 |
|/2. two lines row1 | one       |
                    | two       |
|/2. two lines row2 | one       |
                    | two       |
```

I'm looking for something for SublimeText/VIM/Notepad++ or JS extension to format tables properly in a text file.

Comment: for your 1st example. Vim with Align plugin could do it very easy. however the 2nd table, it's hard to let vim know the 2nd line `| two |` should be at the 2nd column, and leave 1st column empty. it is doable too, e.g. take `/#`, then parse the following `#` lines, add absent `|`s , do align, then remove those `|`s.

Comment: There are [many plugins](http://www.vim.org/scripts/script_search_results.php?keywords=table&script_type=&order_by=creation_date&direction=descending&search=search) on vim.org. Did you do your research before asking?

Comment: I'm not a vim guru and I've made my research around SublimeText and JS and didn't found anything. VIM is less preferable option for me, but I can consider it too and maybe I'll rewrite plugin for it if such exists -- that's why i mentioned vim here. Question is about Textile, but I see you haven't read the results that you gave. There are standard python libs and reStructuredText tables.
besides Align (mentioned by Kent) I can't see there anything suited for textile. and that plugin also isn't excatly what I want

Answer (score 1):

I threw together something to help me with this the other day, and added an output format for textile tables.

http://joecullin.com/data_converter/

You have to choose Redmine table as the output format. I still use this tool every time I want to create a table in redmine. Even for small tables it's easier than typing the markdown by hand. Now I can paste in data from Excel pretty easily, and then paste the result into Redmine.

There are still some kinks in my code, but if I have a large table it gets me to a good starting point quickly. Then I can fix things up by hand. You might look at that code as inspiration if you're considering writing your own javascript.